# multiple-step operation generated errors. check each status value

Tags: vb6

I have two recordset which want to update one of them by value of the other. I did like this

```
 stSql = "SELECT dbo.tblCableProperty.CatalogCode FROM  dbo.tblCable INNER JOIN " & _
"  dbo.tblCableProperty ON dbo.tblCable.CablePcode = dbo.tblCableProperty.CablePcode" & _
" WHERE dbo.tblCable.prjsubcode=" & prjsubcode & " AND dbo.tblCable.Active=1 " & " And dbo.tblCable.Gtag='" & Gtag & "' And dbo.tblCable.TagNo=" & tagno & " And dbo.tblCable.NTag=" & NTag & " And dbo.tblCable.EndStr='" & EndStr & "'"
rs.Open stSql, cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
catalogCode = rs!catalogCode
rs.Close

stSql = "SELECT *,'' as ShowNum FROM viwShowNum WHERE prjsubcode=" & prjsubcode & " AND Active=1 " & " And Gtag='" & Gtag & "' And TagNo=" & tagno & " And NTag=" & NTag & " And EndStr='" & EndStr & "' ORDER BY 8"
rs.Open stSql, cn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
rs.MoveFirst

stSql = "Select * from tblCoreCode where CatalogCode=" & catalogCode
Set rsCoreCode = New ADODB.Recordset
rsCoreCode.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rsCoreCode.Open stSql, cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

While Not rs.EOF
criteria = "RealNum='" & rs!CoreNo & "'"
rsCoreCode.Filter = criteria

rs!ShowNum = CStr(rsCoreCode!ShowNum)
rsCoreCode.Filter = adFilterNone
rs.MoveNext
Wend
```

I get the following error on this part

```
 rs!ShowNum = CStr(rsCoreCode!ShowNum)

 multiple-step operation generated errors. check each status value
```

rsCoreCode!ShowNum is varchar(5). I tried to set the value

```
 rs!ShowNum = "1"
```

but again I got the same error.
where is the problem?

Thank you

Comment: What does this `*,'' ` part mean in the line `stSql = "SELECT *,'' as ShowNum FROM ...`?

Comment: * means all the fields and '' as ShowNum means that I add another field to the recordset to fill it later

Comment: Thanks. Can `as` be used to assign an alias for selected column. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h09t6a82%28v=vs.80%29.aspx Does it create new column?

Comment: how can I append a field to the existing recordset?

Comment: My questions has been real questions.I have been trying to understand your code. Thanks your replies again. For adding new fields: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676135(v=vs.85).aspx Like this may be: `rs.fields.append "ShowNum", adChar, 5, adFldUpdatable`

Comment: What's the value of `rs.Updatable` or `rs!ShowNum.DataUpdatable`  ?

Comment: @Amessihel As I understand there is no way to add a new field to a recordset except created from scratch: "You can only append fields to a Recordset that is not open and has not yet been connected to a data source." https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/223771/

Comment: I edit my answer, the link was bad sorry. Your RecordSet is open, isn't it ? Also you aren't _appending_ a field, but _setting_ one. Check the link in my answer to know if your RecordSet is _updatable_.

Comment: You can't typically update a recordset created with joins. Also, use adOpenKeyset and adLockOptimistic for an updateable recordset.

Comment: Also, this line: `stSql = "SELECT *,'' as ShowNum FROM viwShowNum WHERE prjsubcode=" & prjsubcode & " AND Active=1 " & " And Gtag='" & Gtag & "' And TagNo=" & tagno & " And NTag=" & NTag & " And EndStr='" & EndStr & "' ORDER BY 8"`, you are creating a computed field for ShowNum which is by definition not updateable. If ShowNum is a field in the database, don't include the `'' as ShowNum` portion in your query.

Answer (score 0):

As asked in my comment, if `rs.Updatable` or `rs!ShowNum.DataUpdatable` are `false`, you can use this piece of code from [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb243815%28v=office.12%29.aspx) to retrieve an updatable `RecordSet`.

Comment: I don't have any rs.Updatable or rs!ShowNum.DataUpdatable

Answer (score 0):

Same issue occurred to me the problem was that i violated an object property , in my case it was size the error came out as

"IntegrationException: Problem (Multiple-step operation generated errors. Check each status value.)"

```
Imports ADODB
Dim _RecordSet As Recordset  
_rs.Fields.Append("Field_Name", DataTypeEnum.adVarChar, 50)
_Recordset("Field_Name").Value = _RecordDetails.Field_NameValue
```

_RecordDetails.Field_NameValue length was more than 50 chars , so this property was violated , hence the error occurred , so you should probably check if you didn't match one of the properties